# Two DIVs on the same place

Tags: html, css

My "search box and social icons" are hidden behind my main-menu. This is probably because of my .hide-menu class. I have a jQuery plugin that makes the main-menu appear when scrolling-up and makes it disappear when scrolling-down. 
What I want to achieve is that the "search box and social icons" DIV show always and below the main-menu. Is this possible?

My FIDDLE... [FIDDLE LINK HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/7f6q75h8/)

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.menu-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 border-top: 1px solid #000;
    min-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-nav a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.navbar-nav a:link {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'century schoolbook';
    color: #000;
    /*text-decoration: overline;
    text-decoration-color: #A10000*/
}

.brand-name a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.brand-name img {
    max-width: 137px;
    padding: 8px;
/*position:absolute;*/
    left: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar-form input,.form-inline input {
    width: auto;
}

#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

#sidebar.affix-top {
    position: static;
}

#sidebar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #A10000;
    font-family: 'LuzSans-Book';
    font-size: 15px;
 font-weight:bold
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #A10000;
    color: #000;
 margin-top:4px;
 margin-bottom:4px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    background-color: #000;
 margin-top:4px;
 margin-bottom:4px;
}

.navbar-custom-social {
    height: 15px;
    float: right;
    clear: none;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
    padding-top: 0;
}


#search-social {
 margin-bottom:20px
}

header.site_header {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    -webkit-transition: top .5s;
    transition: top .5s;
    background-color: #fff;
}

header.site_header.hide-menu {
    top: -90px;
}
```

```html
<header class="site_header root" id="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
                        <!-- <div class="clearfix container navbar-fixed-top"> -->
                        <div class="clearfix menu-container">
                            <div class="pull-right clearfix toggle_btn_wrap">
                                <a class="navbar-toggle" data-target=
                                ".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href=
                                "#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-left brand-name">
                                <a href="#"><img alt="NAME" src=
                                "/images/LOGO.png"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix prevent-float"></div>
                            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                MENU ITEMS
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
<div id="search-social" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
                    <div class="clearfix search_and_social">
                        <div class="clearfix navbar navbar-custom-search">
                            SEARCH BOX
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix navbar navbar-custom-social">
                            SOCIAL ICONS
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you clear more on this weather you want both `div` visible at the same time or `search bar` only shown when `menu items` is hidden

Comment: @Rajesh Jangid - search bar has to show always, it is completely separate from menu.

Comment: Why the MINUS 1 ????

Comment: Question is unclear. Had to read it several times to understand exactly what you mean. Also you talk about "hide menu" code. You mean `.hide-menu` class. Then in an answer you ask to show in your example. The minus was because you show very little effort on your part. Removed it for now, but please help us help you. Read [ask]. Also, a sample on eg. jsfiddle.net or link to your site is more useful to see what goes on with the jquery plugin and the scroll.

Comment: @yezzz - I appreciate your comments, but instead of giving me a minus, you could have suggested an edit. I edited my question and hopefully it is clearer now. The answer I received I didnt understand, thats why I asked that if the poster could show me in an example. The SO snippet code works, but I can make a Fiddle also ofcourse, you just have to ask, my friend.

Comment: @yezzz - especially for you I added my Fiddle link.

Comment: You are right about that, that's why I removed the minus. And the question looks clearer now. And the fiddle is useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is probably to use sibling selector between `.site_header` and `#search-social`. Make sure that `#search-social` is positioned. Something like:

```
#search-social {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

header.site_header ~ #search-social {
  top: 40px;
}
header.site_header.hide-menu ~ #search-social {
  top: 0px;
}
```

Example (with a testbutton): https://jsfiddle.net/7f6q75h8/2/

Note: Top styling needs some adjustment depending on the menu height.

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot, also for removing the -1 ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use position:absolute;

Else you can add a class on the wrapper when you wanna show or hide something.

```
.wrapper .active .div2{
   display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want but may lead you in right direction. just added a jquery function to determine the state when menu bar is visible,

```
function adjustMenu() {
   if (!$('#nav').hasClass('hide-menu')) {
      $('#search-social').css('margin-top', $('#nav').height() + 'px');
   } else {
      $('#search-social').css('margin-top', '0px');
   }
}
```

this function is called on page load as well as inside the onscroll event of page

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   adjustMenu();
});
```

here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paw9pb7a/1/)

there are better ways if you can edit in the plugin code you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my question to make it more clear. Hope it helps and sorry for the confusion.